# SharePoint 2013 exclude few documents from search

Tags: 2013, search, search-results, enterprise-search, search-scope

How to exclude specific documents from search rather than entire document library?
Search is configured for all sites and I want to exclude specific documents from search in some of sites.

Comment: Check this http://andreaswijayablog.blogspot.com/2015/09/sharepoint-2013-how-to-exclude-specific.html

Comment: The simplest way is to use security. If the user cannot get to the doc they won't see it in search results.

Comment: Agreed @MatthewMcDermott , but what if they have access and need not see the same in result? answer lies in explicit removal right?

Comment: Or use demotion of the content to make it less authoritative. It begs the question "If the content is so un-valuable why does it exist?"

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott  :) you are initiating new dimension to the question! Good one to ponder! I leave it to Rajan to answer the same from his perspective.

Comment: Yes, Actual issue is user permission not implemented in proper way due to that files are getting displayed in search result as search results are based on user permission. Temporarily solved the problem by changing query on result web part. Thanks M.Qassas, Matthew and John for your suggestion.

Comment: @John :) sometimes explaining the reason or requirement behind the request can help improve the question. "We need to do this thing because..." In this case I had to ask "Why keep the content if you don't want to find it?" To me it sounds like a poor IA for the implementation. We often have folks who want to "store" company content they don't care to "find". We often implement an "Archive Site" for this and get the lawyers to agree to a retention schedule so we can delete it later.

Comment: @Matthew McDermott well said, hope you would have lots of similar experience. Thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 3):

This is absolutely possible. 
Please check the search service and then the crawl log. You can identify the specific document URL and then select remove this from index option.

- Central Administration --> Search service Administration
- Click on Crawl Logs --> Select the content source --> Click the Success Count Link
  [image]
- Select the specific URL from the search bar or if it displays prominatly you can select that URL.
  [image]
- Click on the drop down --> Select Remove the Item from Index

[image]

Second way is that if you get the exact URL, in the search services page, under search results removal you can specify those URLs and it would be reflected almost immediately. 
[image]